# Integration of Singularity within integral

Tags: python, integral, quad

[image: Kramer Kroenig EQ Huang, et al.,]
(Kramer Kroenig EQ Huang, et al.,)

Hello, does anyone know how to integrate the function below to solve for the Phase Amp using Kramers Kroenig Relation's in python. The Integral can be definite through the range of 1.2 - 8 however I am unsure on how to properly integrate the singularity point using the quad function. I have tried specifying singularity points with 'points' and weights like with 'cauchys' I am unsure if I am doing it correctly as the integral goes wild. R(E') takes values from a text file with values for the points of the integral.

```
def reflection_function(energy):
    return np.interp(energy, ref_ener, ref_ref)

def integrand(e_prime, energy):
    return np.log(reflection_function(e_prime))/(e_prime**2 - energy**2)

integral_result = quad(integrand, 1, 8, args=(energy,), weight = 'cauchy', wvar = energy)[0]

print(integral_result)
```

It returns wild values like -220310228.0672309 and it should be around -0.7655680665661697. I am unsure why this is happening. Also I get this error

```
IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
  If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze 
  the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a 
  local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will 
  probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator 
  on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
  integral_result = quad(integrand, 1, 8, args=(energy,), weight =
```

Comment: In `np.interp(energy, ref_ener, ref_ref)` what are `ref_ener` and `ref_ref`? Are they they of reasonable size? What kind of function is being approximated? Some kinds of functions are harder to numerically integrate than others.

Comment: Ref_ref and ref_ener are an approximation of reflection data from a text file. The data was collected experimentally and collected reflectivity as a function of energy. It is a semi smooth curve but cannot be approxmiated by a function.

Comment: reflection_function() isn't the problem. (Assuming energy is within your limits of integration) you are trying to integrate something proportional to 1/(e_prime^2 - energy^2) straight through e_prime=energy and the integrand has a simple pole there. You would have exactly the same problem integrating 1/x between x=-1 and +1. It doesn't converge as a Riemann integral and you would have to decide what sort of limiting procedure (e.g. a small and equal gap either side of the singularity - the "Cauchy principal value") is required here

Comment: How would I properly integrate it when e_prime = energy. This can be simplified around -1/(x^2-2^2) how would I integrate and implement Cauchy principal value in python.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `weight="cauchy", wvar=energy` will automatically apply a weighting `1/(eprime-energy)` associated with this pole, so this doesn't need to be included in the integrand.

Thus, you can keep your statement using quad, but you need to send it a modified integrand:

```
def integrand(e_prime, energy):
    return np.log(reflection_function(e_prime))/(e_prime + energy)     # the rest

integral_result = quad(integrand, 1, 8, args=(energy,), weight = 'cauchy', wvar = energy)[0]
```

(This does assume that your reflection_function is positive, but since we can't see it we can't do anything about that.)

I'm also assuming that your energy is positive - use the other pole if not.

As a simpler example, the following program would find the principal value of the integral of 1/(x<sup>2</sup>-1) from 0 to 3. The integrand has a simple pole at x=1, so is modified in the call to quad by removing the factor (x-1) from the denominator. The principal value at the end should be (1/2)ln(1/2), or -0.34657...

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand_modified( x ):
    return 1.0 / ( x + 1.0 )

i = quad(integrand_modified, 0.0, 3.0, weight='cauchy', wvar = 1.0 )[0]
print( i )
```

Comment: So this would return the correct integral essentially?
Does it assume in the denominator there is also (e_prime - energy)?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the documentation, that is what your combination of weight and wvar options will do. (You can also check it with my simpler integral if you do the principal integral by hand.)

Comment: Ok that makes sense and resolved a lot of my issue. I am now having issues however with integrating np.log(reflection(e_prime)) within the data range of 1.2 - 8.0. It is data from experimental data and I am getting the integrand warning 
that the maximum number of subdivisions has occurred. How do I stop this error? Should I use trapezoid integration and if so how would I combine that with Cauchy?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to do any more without seeing a complete code (and the data). We have no idea what your function reflection() is doing. Also need the value of energy.

Comment: Ok, I resolved the problem. Thank you so much for the help though!